# String with two conditions passed to CodeIgniter's where() method breaks query

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

```
$this->db->select('sum(commission_amount) as myamount');
$this->db->from('forex_commissions');
$this->db->where('createdDate_sql = `2020-02-16`  and userRef = `MXkIP8z0vs5J`');
$result = $this->db->get();
```

If I run my query as raw SQL it works, but when I try to transcribe it to CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord method calls, it returns `false`.

Comment: Values should be surrounded by single or double quotes, not backticks. But using [proper parameterization would be better](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: i tried with single and double quotes as well

Comment: What's in `$this->db->error();` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using `->db->where()` properly. The correct codeigniter way of your example is:

```
  $this->db->select('sum(commission_amount) as myamount');
  $this->db->from('forex_commissions');
  $this->db->where('createdDate_sql', '2020-02-16');
  $this->db->where('userRef', 'MXkIP8z0vs5J');
  $result = $this->db->get();
```

using this syntax also escapes all values automatically, producing safer queries. see [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

note: you can also echo your latest query executed with: `echo $this->db->last_query();`

Comment: CodeIgniter method reference: [`select_sum()`](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#:~:text=%24this%2D%3Edb%2D%3Eselect_sum())